# Create Vendor Bill from Netsuite Item Fulfillment or Item Receipt

Tags: netsuite

It is especially difficult in large Netsuite orders to do receipts and billing, considering we are using Advanced Receiving and are going into a particular order multiple times and partially receiving each time.  Is there a way in Netsuite to create a Vendor Bill based on the final contents of a particular Item Fulfillment (if Drop Shipped) or Item Receipt?

Answer (score 1):

**Billing Purchase Orders**

Billing a purchase order indicates you have received an invoice from the vendor for items purchased and creates a bill in accounts payable. You can turn your purchase order into a bill without rekeying any data.

If you use Advanced Receiving, you can receive an order and create a bill in separate steps. To enable advanced receiving, go to Setup > Enable Features. On the Purchase Transactions subtab, check the Advanced Receiving box, and click Save.

> Note:
>   When you create a standalone bill or bill an existing purchase order, the transaction >requires an active Accounts Payable account. For an active account, you must enable an >existing Accounts Payable account, create a new Accounts Payable account, or contact your >System Administrator.

To bill a purchase order with Advanced Receiving:

1. Go to Transactions > Purchases/Vendors > Bill Purchase Orders.
2. On the Bill Purchase Orders page, in the Vendor field, select a vendor to create bills for.

   - You can select All to show all open bills, but you can create bills for only one vendor at a time.
3. Check the box in the Bill column next to all purchase orders you want to bill.

   - If you check more than one purchase order, items from all the purchase orders you check are grouped together on one bill.
4. Click Submit.

   - The bill appears and shows the purchase order items.

     - If Match Bill to Receipt is enabled on the purchase order when the vendor bill is created, you can select specific receipts in the Receipts column. Then, the values on the receipt determine the following:

       - A bill is created for specific receipts that are selected.
       - The bill is checked against receipt values for variances.
5. If the information on the bill is correct, click Save.